# powershell function output to variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a function in powershell 2.0 named getip which gets the IP address(es) of a remote system.

```
function getip {
$strComputer = "computername"

$colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"



ForEach ($objItem in $colItems)

{Write-Host $objItem.IpAddress}

}
```

The problem I'm having is with getting the output of this function to a variable. The folowing doesn't work...

```
$ipaddress = (getip)
$ipaddress = getip
set-variable -name ipaddress -value (getip)
```

any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly this would work? (If you use `Write-Host`, the data will be output, not returned).

```
function getip {
    $strComputer = "computername"

    $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"

    ForEach ($objItem in $colItems) {
        $objItem.IpAddress
    }
}


$ipaddress = getip
```

`$ipaddress` will then contain an array of string IP addresses.

Comment: More specifically, Write-Host sends the data directly to the console host or stdout of the process.

Write-Output or not capturing the output (as in Nate's example) will send the output to "stdout" of the current pipeline or function.  This is approximately the same behavior as "echo" in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

you can allso do

```
function getip {
    $strComputer = "computername"

    $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"

    ForEach ($objItem in $colItems) {
        write-output $objItem.IpAddress
    }
}


$ipaddress = getip
```

for accessing within the pipline you should use return/write-output

Answer (score 2):

the problem in a nutshell is, that `Write-Host` **cannot** be redirected.

You can use this behaviour to your advantage, for example to return information to the user which will not be captured when he redirects your function's return value, to store it in a variable, but is visible nonetheless.

Use:

- `Write-Host` to write directly to the **(shell) process** - not to a stream
- `Write-Output` to write to **success-/output-stream**.

  - redirect only the *success-stream* to file: `Write-Output "success message" 1>output_stream_messages.txt`
  - store in variable: `$var=Write-Output "output message"`
  - Note: variable assignment always and **only** redirects the *output-/success-stream*. Other streams are left untouched
- `Write-Error` to write to the **error-stream**

  - redirect only the *error-stream* to file: `Write-Error "error message" 2>error_stream_messages.txt`
  - store in variable: `$var=Write-Error "Error message" 2>&1`
  - Note: This actually redirects the *error-stream* to the *success-stream*. Data already in the *success-stream* is **not** overwritten, but appended). As the *error output* is now in the *success-stream* (as well) we can store it in a variable by redirecting/assigning the *success-stream data* to the variable `$var`.
- `Write-Warning`to write to the **warning-stream**

  - redirect only the *warning-stream* to file: `Write-Warning "warning message" 3>warning_stream_messages.txt`
  - store in variable: `$var=Write-Warning "Warning message" 3>&1`
- `Write-Verbose` to write to the **verbose-stream**

  - redirect only the *verbose-stream* to file: `Write-Verbose "verbose message" -Verbose 4>verbose_stream_messages.txt`
  - store in variable: `$var=Write-Verbose "Verbose message" -Verbose 4>&1`
  - Note: The `-Verbose`is necessary because the default powershell setting does not output verbose messages. (As defined by the preference variable `$VerbosePreference`, which is usually *"SilentlyContinue"*. You can also set it to `$VerbosePreference="Continue"` before evoking the command (in the current powershell session/environment) as to not need the switch `-Verbose`.) Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6) for more info about *powershell preference variables*.
- `Write-Debug`to write to the **debug-stream**

  - redirect only the debug stream to file: `Write-Debug "debug message" -Debug 5>debug_stream_messages.txt`
  - store in variable: `$var=Write-Debug "Debug message" -Debug 5>&1`
  - Note: Depending on your setting of the *$DebugPreference* variable, your powershell may pause and inquire your input for the next action of choice. Set `$DebugPreference="Continue"` as to get rid of this behaviour and also lose the need for the `-Debug` switch **before** evoking the command.

You can use `*>&1` to redirect all streams to the *success-stream* and then redirect it as you see fit. (Storing it in a variable or redirecting it to *$null* or a file or something like that.)

For more details I recommend a very good article about [powershell's streams on devblogs.microsoft.com](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)