# Powershell store function returned value into a variable

Tags: powershell

I have found a great answer on Stack Overflow that explains how to have a powershell function that runs some SQL to return a single value.

What I'm not understanding is how to call the function and place the result into a variable that I can use later? Any help would be appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22715645/2461666

```
[string] $Server= "10.0.100.1",
[string] $Database = "Database123",
[string] $SQLQuery= $("SELECT [FeedID] FROM [dbo].[FeedList] WHERE [FeedFileName] = 'filename.txt'")

function GenericSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLQuery) {
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
    while ($Reader.Read()) {
         $Reader.GetValue($1)
    }
    $Connection.Close()
}
```

This is what I am currently trying but it doesn't seem to be working at all...

```
$myvariable = GenericSqlQuery
```

Comment: Are the values for `$server`, `$Database` and `$SQLQuery` correct for you application? I suspect not as they are exactly the same as the values in the linked example. Make sure the values are correct for your database and schema then try again.

Comment: Apologies, yes in my environment I am specifying the correct server details. I've added some logging to my function so I can confirm that it is properly querying the database and returning the value I need.... I'm just having an issue with calling the function and saving it's result to a variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the way I have got it to work for me in this situation is to pass the value to a variable within my function and then within my function return the variable like this....

```
while ($Reader.Read()) {
     $SQLResult = $Reader.GetValue($1) 
     return $SQLResult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome to see you searched stack overflow for an answer first Tommy!

Think I found another one to help you!

**I have found something that may help:**
[powershell function output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017317/powershell-function-output-to-variable)

*Below is from the above link*

```
function getip {
    $strComputer = "computername"

    $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"

    ForEach ($objItem in $colItems) {
        $objItem.IpAddress
    }
}


$ipaddress = getip
```